# Neverwinter & Sword Coast adventures

Tags: dnd-5e, game-recommendation, published-adventures, online-resources, lost-mine-of-phandelver

We're a new group of D&D 5e players and I've been DMing the Lost Mines of Phandelver with a great deal of success.

What I am looking for for my group are a few good resources that will help flesh out the Sword Coast and Neverwinter. I'd really like an adventure set in Neverwinter.

Are there any sites that I should specifically be looking at for this type of content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want something that fits in directly with the time period of the Forgotten Realms as depicted in Phandelver then the new Princes of the Apocalypse adventure starts out just to the east of  Phandelver.

I have the book and the initial adventures are in the Dessarin Valley. The north end begins at the eastern terminus of the Triboar trail as you can see in this map.

http://mikeschley.zenfolio.com/p763166286/h1c53b7b4#h1c53b7b4

Wyvern Tor is in the Northwest corner.

The premiere website for all things Forgotten Realms is [Candlekeep](http://www.candlekeep.com/)

You could get a copy of the [original information](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/16802/FR1-Waterdeep-and-the-North-1e?it=1&filters=0_44710_0) on the Sword Coast from D&D Classics. I recommend Waterdeep and the North. I have a copy myself and it has a lot of information about the Sword Coast area. However it is for an earlier time period than what in Phandelver.

D&D Classics [has Forgotten Realms material spanning](http://www.dndclassics.com/browse.php?filters=0_44710_0) all eras.

The most recent material they have on Neverwinter, is the [Lost Crown of Neverwinter for 4e](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/121733/Lost-Crown-of-Neverwinter-4e?term=neverwinter&filters=0_44710_0). I played and referee as part of a game store campaign and it quite good and has a lot of roleplaying opportunities with different factions. Although it is a bit episodic as it oriented to a weekly D&D Encounters session.

What is a really good Neverwinter resource is Jaquay's [the Savage Frontier](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/17554/FR5-The-Savage-Frontier-1e?term=Neverwinter&filters=0_44710_0&it=1) from the original Forgotten Realms run. Again it is set in a earlier time period.

You may want to look at this [Candlekeep forum thread](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=17681) for Neverwinter resources.

Comment: HOTDQ is also set in the same area, it starts well south, but passes pretty close by. It does not however, get all the way up to Neverwinter.

Comment: RS Conley thanks for the resources. These will keep me going. Also +1 for alluding to the time period. I was going to add this to the question originally. I guess for the 4e stuff I need to find some advice on migrating to 5e. @waxeagle cheers for the HOTDQ note. I'll probably let my characters get really comfortable with the Neverwinter area for a few months, the steer them out of their comfort zone with this!